# Why does raising this polynomial to a power, give the correct answer for a combinatorics problem?

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, exponentiation

The problem I was trying to solve is this:

> A thief made his way to a shop.
>
> As usual he has his lucky knapsack with him. The knapsack can contain $k$ objects. There are $n$ kinds of products in the shop and an infinite number of products of each kind. The cost of one product of kind $i$ is $a_i$.
>
> The thief is greedy, so he will take exactly $k$ products (it's possible for some kinds to take several products of that kind).
>
> Find all the possible total costs of products the thief can nick into his knapsack.

The solution described is as follows:

> Let $k  = 2$, then this is the standard problem that can be solved with the help of FFT (fast Fourier transform). And it is solved as follows: consider a polynomial in which the coefficient of the $i^{th}$ power is equal to one if and only if in the given array there is a number $i$. Let's raise this polynomial to a square, then those $i$ coefficient for which the squared is not equal to $0$ will be in the answer. It is easy to generalize this solution to the case of an arbitrary $k$. You just need to raise the initial polynomial to the $k^{th}$ power. This, of course, needs to be done with the help of binary exponentiation. The complexity is $O(WlogWlogk)$, where $W$ is the maximum sum.

I have no idea why this works so I need some explanation about it. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know about generating functions?

Comment: Try this for $n=4,k=2.$  Then the polynomial is $(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4)^2$  The various terms in the product correspond to the ways to choose 2 items. $x_1^2$ is nicking 2 of item 1.  $x_2x_3$ is taking an item 2 and an item 3.